# Why binding pdst with the target ip address and binding a broadcast mac address instead of the target mac address

Tags: python, scapy, arp, spoofing

In 'The Black Hat Python' book page number 53 the restore_target.
Why We specify the ip address of the gateway and not specifying its mac address ? I mean if we're going to broadcast our ARP packet then why give pdst value of a specific ip address instead of a broadcast ip address like the hwdst ? ?

```
send(ARP(op=2, psrc=gateway_ip, pdst=target_ip, hwdst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff",hwsrc=gateway_mac),count=5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're sending here is called a *Gratuitous ARP*.
It's a special kind of packets, defined by the fact that the destination Mac is `ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`.

Have a look at: https://www.practicalnetworking.net/series/arp/gratuitous-arp/

The difference is that it is an answer packet, even if there was no request packet. It's "gratuitous". In your case, you are sending a packet mapping `psrc` to `hwsrc`, sent to everyone: the router is advertising his MAC to everyone.

In this case, `pdst` has little meaning, but it should be set by convention to the same address than `psrc`. I don't know why it was different in your example.

Comment: It's not my code it's written in the "The Black hat python", so I also don't know the reason. 
Why we have to set the `pdst` to the same address than `psrc` ?

Comment: That's just how it is in the RFC.